# What is the smallest possible basis for the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of all real numbers, and let $\mathscr{T}$ be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $U \in \mathscr{T}$ if and only if $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$ is either finite or all of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, called the finite complement, or co-finite, topology.

Now $\mathscr{T}$ itself is a basis for this topology, but can we determine a basis for $\mathscr{T}$ that is contained in every other basis for $\mathscr{T}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a non-discrete T$_1$ topology cannot have a minimal base.

For suppose $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for such a topology. Then we can choose $B \in \mathscr{B}$ with $|B|\gt 1$, since a topology with a base consisting only of singleton sets is discrete.

We show that $\mathscr{B}$ is not minimal by showing that 
$$ \mathscr{B}^\prime \colon= \mathscr{B} \setminus \{B\} $$ 
is a base for the topology, and we show that by showing that $B$ is a union of sets in $\mathscr{B}^\prime$.

Consider any point $x \in B$; we have to find a set $B^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime$ such that 
$$ x\in B^\prime \subseteq B.$$

Since $|B|\gt1$, we can choose a point $y\in B$ such that $y \neq x$. As the topology is T$_1$, so there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \not\in U$.

Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a base, there is a set $B^\prime \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $$ x \in B^\prime \subseteq B\cap U.$$ 
Since $y \not\in U$, therefore $y \not\in B \cap U$ either and thus $y \notin B^\prime$, but as $y \in B$, so we have $B^\prime \neq B$. Thus $B^\prime \in \mathscr{B}$ and $B^\prime \neq B$; that is, 
$$ B^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime.$$

In particular, the *cofinite* topology on an *infinite* set is a non-discrete T$_1$ topology, so it has no minimal base.

Answer (score 11):

Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{U\in\mathscr{T}:|\Bbb R\setminus U|\text{ is even}\}$ and $\mathscr{B}_1=\{U\in\mathscr{T}:|\Bbb R\setminus U|\text{ is odd}\}$. $\mathscr{B}_0$ and $\mathscr{B}_1$ are both bases for $\mathscr{T}$, but $\mathscr{B}_0\cap\mathscr{B}_1=\varnothing$, so $\mathscr{T}$ has no base that is a subset of both $\mathscr{B}_0$ and $\mathscr{B}_1$ and therefore no smallest base.

Comment: how to verify that both $\mathscr{B}_0$ and $\mathscr{B}_1$ satisfy the two conditions for being a basis?

Comment: @Saaqib: Since you know the topology, you need only check one condition: $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\mathscr{T}$ is and only if for each $U\in\mathscr{T}$ and $x\in U$ there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

Comment: is it then possible to obtain a basis for our finite-complement topology that does not contained in any other basis? Please also explain the difference between the terms "smallest" and "minimal", as well as the terms "base" and "basis". Regards.

Comment: @Saaqib: There is no difference here between *base* and *basis*; they’re two names for the same thing. *Smallest* means that it’s contained in every other base; *minimal* means that no other base is properly contained in it. That is, $\mathscr{B}_0$ is a minimal base for $\mathscr{T}$ if there is no base $\mathscr{B}$ such that $\mathscr{B}\subsetneqq\mathscr{B}_0$. $\mathscr{B}_0$ is the smallest base for $\mathscr{T}$ if $\mathscr{B}_0\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ for every base $\mathscr{B}$ for $\mathscr{T}$. The smallest base, if there is one, is always minimal; a minimal base need not be ...

Comment: ... smallest. My answer shows that there is no base smallest base, no base that is contained in all bases. **bof**’s answer shows that if $\mathscr{B}$ is any base for $\mathscr{T}$, there is a smaller one: you can throw away any member of $\mathscr{B}$, and what’s left is still a base for $\mathscr{T}$. Finally, $\mathscr{T}$ itself is the largest base for itself: it obviously contains every base for itself.